# OS X 10.7.4 Wi-Fi 802.11d network interface country code switching

Tags: macos, wifi

So I live in Sweden and since a couple of days ago one of my neighbors are broadcasting country code "US" from their AP, rendering my newly awaken MBA 2011 confused, so after a couple of seconds it changes the country code on the wireless interface to "US" and my own network SSID disappears.

Apparently this functionality is according to the specifications of the [802.11d protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11d-2001) and simplifies manufacturing and country specific regulations for wireless equipment.

This so called "feature" is making my life a real pain for the moment and I'd rather not re-configure my own AP to a channel which is included in both the US and SE/EU array of accepted channels for a number of reasons.

Is there a way to disable this country code switching functionality in OS X 10.7.4?

Comment: one more in sweden, suffering...
two macbookpros ..killing me ..
I hv this Asus RT-n56u
(before this I had some MIMO pre-n router, no issues whatsoever. Why-o-why did I throw that away ..) @Samir - did u manage to try a channel that works in Sweden?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I am aware of (Believe me I've looked). I had this issue too (See my blog post here: http://jeff-with-a-g.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/5ghz-wifi-on-your-mac-got-you-down.html).

In the end I had to choose a channel that worked in all of the regulatory domains that my neighbours' wireless access points were broadcasting. That may be a bit trickier in Europe given the smaller number of channels available.

This doesn't seem to affect Macs running Snow Leopard so I guess it's an issue with Lion. Maybe Mountain Lion will provide a fix.

Answer (score 0):

In OS X Mavericks, I was able to get the country code to reset by going into the Network System Preference pane and deleting the Wifi Interface (selecting it and clicking the little minus at the bottom of the list) and then re-adding a Wifi interface (clicking the + button, choosing Wifi as the type, and naming it Wi-Fi).

I haven't tested this in 10.7, but thought I'd post this here in case it works.